# Is it possible for this to be an infinite loop?

Tags: c++

I am looking for advice on the following function:

```
void f( std::vector<short> v ){
   for(unsigned int i=0; i < v.size(); ++i){
       // anything
   }
}
```

My code looks like this, but someone told me it's possible for this to loop forever.  I don't understand what conditions might cause that, because it looks normal to me.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you feel there could be an infinite loop? Can a `vector` have an infinite size? Perhaps "someone" could explain their thoughts a bit more.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for here.  What you've given is boiler plate code for a `for` loop in C++.  As written it won't be an infinity loop which is good but your `//anything` section easily could make it so.  For example, replace `//anything` with `i--;` and you've got yourself an infinity loop.  There's no high level guidance we can give you outside of what you have right now isn't an infinity loop

Comment: This will loop infinitely in the case where your vector size exceeds `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`, which for example might be the case on some 64-bit systems where `std::vector<T>::size_type` is a larger type than `unsigned int`.  In that case, the `unsigned int` will overflow before ever satisfying the terminating condition.  `size_t` is a more appropriate type to use as your loop variable.

Comment: I have rolled back your changes to the question, which had removed all useful information from the question.  I don't know why this question was downvoted heavily and closed.  As my comment above points out, it _is_ possible for this to loop indefinitely.  I guess that perhaps people didn't stop to think about it for long enough.

Comment: Thank you soo much @paddy, I got the answer which I am looking for and you are comments help me a lot.

Comment: Note that there are alternatives to index-based iteration.  You could use standard iterators, or range-based loops.  Separately, it should be mentioned that your vector is being passed _by value_, and that might not be necessary.  Most commonly, a vector is passed by reference -- either modifiable or const.  This is for efficiency, and certainly in the case you're worried about where perhaps the vector might hold more than 2^32 - 1 values on a system where `unsigned int` is 4 bytes, that's a heck of a lot of memory to be copying if you don't need a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this might very well be an infinite loop.

```
void f( std::vector<short> v )
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
       // anything
    }
}
```

`v.size()` is a `size_t`, which on some platform, like mine is 64-bit unsigned. So, a value like `2^63` is possible.

`unsigned int`, might be smaller than `size_t`. So, it's quite possible the largest possible `unsigned int` be `2^32 - 1`, on your platform. So, if you receive a big enough vector, the `unsigned int` value in your loop will always be smaller than the size of that specific vector. Thus your loop will never exit.

Comment: `int` is signed but the code only uses `unsigned int`.  The issue is not a signed/unsigned mismatch or the shift in representable values due to the sign bit, the issue is potential difference in size between `size_type` and `unsigned_int`.

Comment: right, let me correct. I guess I saw too many colleagues compare `int` and `size_t` :-)